# Carregar css e js do active admin do rails no apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Amigos resolvi postar esta duvida após muita pesquisa e tentativas sem sucesso. 
Estou configurando uma VPS, onde nela, está sendo hospedado um site que contem uma seção de administração. o Front eh em react e o Back em Ruby. A seçao de adm foi feita com o ActiveAdmin do ruby.
Eis o problema: O site ta rodando legal, mas na hora de acessar /admin os css e js nao carregam. Segue meu arquivo .conf do apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName meusite.com.br
    ProxyRequests off
    SSLEngine On
    DocumentRoot /var/www/meusite/build
    ErrorLog /var/www/meusite/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/meusite/log/access.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/meusite/meusite.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/meusite/meusite.key

    <Directory /var/www/meusite/build>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Location /admin>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3002/admin/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3002/admin/
    </Location>

    <Location /api>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:3002/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3002/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

production.rb

```
    Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?


  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "bicos-api_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false


  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    port:           '587',
    address:        'smtp.gmail.com',
    user_name:      ENV['SMTP_USER_NAME'],
    password:       ENV['SMTP_PASSWORD'],
    domain:         ENV['SMTP_DOMAIN'],
    authentication: :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['DEFAULT_URL'], protocol: 'https' }

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false    

end

Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {
  host: ENV['DEFAULT_URL']
}
```

Comment: não dá nenhum erro de `not found` no console?

Comment: Olá, pode postar seu arquivo production.rb?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves da sim... na maioria das vezes da o 404 e a mensagem diz q nao consegue encontrar os resources e as vezes tbm da o seguinte erro Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Comment: @DimitriusLachi ai está: